# How to make my controls appear in Visual Studio's live visual tree tool window when "just my xaml" is enabled?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

When "just my xaml" is enabled, my UserControl-derived controls which don't include a XAML file do not show up in the live visual tree. My controls which have XAML files and are in the same project (same namespace, in fact) *do* show up.

I want all of my controls to show up without having to disable "just my xaml".

How me do?

EDITED since it was requested, here is an example of the XAML in one of the controls that appears. Since all controls with (even boilerplate) XAML appear and none of the controls without it do, I don't think the contents of the XAML makes a difference ..

(Also, to be clear, the "live visual tree" is a Visual Studio tool window that shows the visual structure of your WPF application as it runs. Everything works as expected in the app itself.)

```
<controls:UxpFactContentControl x:Class="TheTree.UxOne.Controls.UxpActionContentControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:TheTree.UxOne.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="100">
    <Button x:Name="ActionButton" Click="OnActionClicked" />
</controls:UxpFactContentControl>
```

Comment: Please, share your xaml code

Comment: @Pavel done, with explanation